# Mac Mini (Late 2009) - Recommended OSX Version for it?

Tags: macos, upgrade, memory, mac-mini, performance

I have a `Mac mini (Late 2009)` (hw.model: `Macmini3,1`, 2 GB RAM) that I've got hooked on my TV primary as a "media consumption" device... but a while ago I updated it to:

`Mac-mini:~ javier$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.5
BuildVersion:   12F2518`

and it crawls along, which is quite painful. I'm debating whether upgrading it to Mavericks or Yosemite might bring some relief for performance... I don't need a blazing computer, but taking 2 minutes to load VLC is a bit too much IMO...

I have thought about upgrading the RAM and maybe getting a better (larger) HD as 160 GB isn't too much these days, but I don't know if that might be throwing money down the sink...

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: I have the same model, upgraded to 8 GB RAM. Running 10.9.5. It crawls too. But not so much like you said. With RAM upgrade from 4 to 8 GB, improved the performance. Now thinking to upgrade to El Capitan. Let us know your experience.

Comment: Keep in mind that 4GB might be the max supported amount of RAM for your system due to hardware limitations.

Comment: An SSD would probably be the best value for a speed increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Mac Mini late 2009 as well. I upgraded the HD to an SSD and the RAM to the max 8GB.  Runs faster than a new i5 notebook with similar specs. There's life in the old girl yet.  After 7 years needed to replace the CPU fan, and the Magic Mouse died. USB mouse solved that but I lost he swipe capabilities. Nice little box.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?  This reads like commentary.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question, in short: It is always advised that you have the **latest possible** OS for your computer. This is due to the myriad of bug fixes and security patches that come along with new OS updates and intermediary releases.

I would suggest bumping up the RAM to the highest possible as well, but at least to 4GB. This should result in an immediate performance boost and result in smoother system operation. Switching the HDD can also help, but is less urgent.

If all else fails, you can always try restoring the operating software to a new state. Often, systems will change over time and become loaded down with old/unpatched/inefficient software and/or changes made to files that result in degraded performance. A new clean wipe will ensure you are running the best software available for the machine.

Comment: I agree - a RAM upgrade is the single best thing you can do to increase performance of that machine. 2GB is definitely not enough for a recent version of Mac OS. Upgrading to 4GB or more (I'd recommend 8GB as RAM is cheap) should increase performance markedly.

Comment: el Capitan is supposed to be a lot faster too, so I'd look at going as far as that once it's available. If you want to squeeze another few years out of it, apart from the above suggestions, an SSD would really bring it back to life. it has done for my 08 Mac Pro.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've bitten the bullet and pressed the "update" button when the Apple Store started pestering me with moving to El Capitan. Still on the process-will update on results!!

Comment: Update to El Capitan was successful-- in that the machine still works. Still not very useable for GUI work. once an app launches (i.e. browser) it's useable but painfully slow. Via SSH for CLI it's ok

Comment: I'll probably try bumping the ram and HD and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I have found that while my mac mini late 2009 was usable upto mavericks, it wasnt a nice experience mainly due to apples aweful choice of the super slow 5200rpm 2.5 inch hd (it was subpar even when it was launched).

So instead of going all out ssd (which would be best performance, but costly to get 1gb of space), I opted to buy a hybrid hard drive (this one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Seagate-Laptop-Solid-State-Hybrid/dp/B00BHRWHNI), this is basically a small ssd with a large normal hd.

On mavericks it made the mac mini feel like a new mac! The drive basically moves the most common apps and files to the ssd part and so you get mad speed most of the time. all at £60 - you cant that kind of bang for your buck with pure ssd.

Plus, now with el capitan update, the mac is faster still.

I still have the option of replacing the ram (currently at 4gb), which will probably the last thing I can do to this little machine.

Answer (score 1):

I've strived to get at least 10 years of life out of all my Macs starting back in the 80's.

So when I updated to OS X 10.11, El Capitan, on my late 2009 Mac Mini I felt like something was dying.

Needless to say, the 2GB RAM is not sufficient but a very affordable 8GB upgrade (US$46) was well worth it. Now all my newer OS devices play nice and I'm happy to push onward for four more years.

Answer (score 0):

I run 10.6.8 and have absolutely no problem with the OS or specific apps "crawling along" (I have 4GB RAM and a spinning disk HD). I am using it to stream videos on Netflix and Amazon without issue. Judging from your question I would thus advise other users against updating OSX to versions later than 10.6.8. These "upgrades" may compatible with such an old Mac Mini but may bring it to a crawl. (The only problem with having such an outdated version of the OS is that it is no longer possible to update Chrome & Firefox to the most recent versions. This together with an old OS probably constitutes an overall security issue.)